# Hide columns in google sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google scripting and have a huge set of data, which I would like to hide certain columns with a script.
The script should be able to hide column C-E. column I and column K-CI.
This should be done in the first 15 sheets. After that sheet 16 and 17 should not hide anything.
I have looked around the web, but I can't figure out how to even though it's pretty basic.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The first 15 sheets are **the first 15 elements** of the `ss.getSheets()`
  array. To get the first 15 elements you can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

  ```
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().slice(0,15);
  ```
- Next, you want to iterate over `sheets` and **for each sheet** apply the
  [hideColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn) function **for every range** in `hRanges` list. To
  accomplish that you can use **two** [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) functions:

  ```
  sheets.forEach(sh=>  
      hRanges.forEach(r=>sh.hideColumn(sh.getRange(r)))
  );
  ```

---

### Solution:

- You are looking for something like that:

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheets = ss.getSheets().slice(0,15);
    const hRanges = ['C1:E1','I1','K1:CI1'];

    sheets.forEach(sh=>
    hRanges.forEach(r=>sh.hideColumn(sh.getRange(r)))
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this awesome explanation. Lesson learned ;)